# Will the -s at the end of "très" be always pronounced?

Tags: prononciation

I have been thinking that if a word beginning with a vowel (a, i, u, e, o) follows right after a word ending in a consonant then this consonant will be pronounced.

Example.

- *Je suis une personne.*
  Here, will the word "suis" be pronounced as "suis" without s ?
- *Je suis très sociable.* In this second  example will "suis" be pronounced as "sui"?

But how about "très optimiste"? Will the -s in "très" be pronounced too?

Answer (score 7):

A word ending with a consonant followed by a word starting with a vowel is necessary but not sufficient for a liaison.

This rules out any liaison in:

> *Je suis très sociable.* Neither the final s of *suis*, nor the final s of *très* is pronounced.

That doesn't mean final consonants are never pronounced in French. There are many words where they are, but this is unrelated to your question.

A potential liaison belongs to one of three groups:

- Mandatory liaisons. Not doing them is considered a mistake whatever the language register.

> *Le**s a**vions* (the planes). Always pronounced with a liaison, no exception.
>
> *Je suis trè**s o**ptimiste.* Liaison may be missed in colloquial relaxed French, depending on the speaker.

- Optional liaisons. These are more often realized in formal than in colloquial  speech.

This group is the larger one:

> *Je sui**s u**ne personne.* My impression is that a liaison is often not realized.

- Forbidden ones. Realizing such a liaison is considered a mistake.

> *Le présiden**t a**utrichien.*

Note that what group a liaison belongs to is not set in stone. There have been changes in the past and there are a few ongoing ones.

For example [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais) states the liaison after *très* is optional but in other sources, e.g. [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3549) and [FLE](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm), it is mandatory.

Finally, note that semi-vowels are definitely compatible with *liaisons*, e.g.:

> /j/ *Dans te**s y**eux.* (mandatory liaison)
>
> /ɥ/ *Une sauce san**s hui**le.* (mandatory liaison)
>
> /w/ Il respire avec se**s ouï**es (mandatory liaison)

As usual, there are exceptions:

> Le**s oui** et les non (forbidden liaison<sup>1</sup>)

---

Also, note that an *h* can influence the liaison, depending on whether its an [aspirated *h*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_h) ("*h* aspiré") or not. Both are silent, but the aspirated *h* prevents the liaison. Normal rules apply if the *h* is not aspirated.

> De**s hi**stoires (not aspirated, liaison)
>
> Des hiboux (aspirated, no liaison)

You can find the complete list of words with an aspirated *h* on the wikipedia page.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>***Oui*** behaves exactly as if it had started with an aspirated *H*: "*Houi*"</sub>

Comment: So Je suis très optimiste, should be pronunced with the trés and not tré?

Comment: I always pronounce it with a liaison.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Wikipedia states *très* belongs to the optional liaisons group but I believe it is still a mandatory one.

Comment: Question: is the liaison after *suis* mandatory if it's followed by a past participle, as in *je suis arrivé*?

Comment: @PeterShor It's optional in *je sui**s a**rrivé.*

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is pronounced, but only in those cases when a liaison is required and then its pronunciation is not the expected one (/s/) but /z/.

- Je suis allé dans ce magasin. /ʒə sɥizale dɑ̃…/

The liaison is required before vowel sounds but not before  semi-vowels sounds (/j/, /ɥ/,  /w/).
(« […] généralement, en français, les semi-voyelles ne donnent pas lieu à élision ou liaison. », [réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-voyelle))

*The  semi-vowels in French and typical words in which they are found*

```
/j/, comme dans yeux [jø], fille [fij], abeille [abɛj];  

/ɥ/ comme dans huile [ɥil], lui [lɥi] ;  

/w/ comme dans oui [wi], jouet [ʒwɛ], moi [mwa].
```

There are a great number of exceptions and some cases when it is not considered to be an error not to make a liaison although certain people think it is better to respect those liaisons. Here is  a good introduction to the question of liaisons: [liaisons](https://lewebpedagogique.com/ressources-fle/files/2011/02/R%C3%A8gle-de-la-liaison.pdf).

*Examples*

- Je suis au téléphone, ne me dérange pas. /ʒə sɥizo te.le.fɔn…/
- Je suis oisif. /ʒə sɥi wa.zif/
- Je suis ailleurs. /ʒə sɥiza.jœʁ/

It follows then that in "je suis optimiste" the s is pronounced, just as in "très optimiste".

- /ʒə sɥizɔp.ti.mist/
- /\tʁɛzɔp.ti.mist/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103929/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-will-the-s-at-the-end-of-tres-be-always-pronounce).